# Copying files from a linux machine to an aws ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, pipeline

I want to write a jenkins pipeline in which at a particular step i have to copy few zip files from a different linux machine. The pipeline will be running on an AWS EC2 agent.
I have to copy the zip files from linux machine to AWS EC2 instance.

i tried using few ways to handle this using curl and scp but not able to achieve it. Is there a better way to achieve it.

With curl : i am facing connection reset by peer error. Please help

[image]

Comment: *i tried using few ways to handle this using curl and scp but not able to achieve it* Share your attempts. What error messages do you see? `scp` is what I would use

Answer (score 1):

I would use `scp` for this task. Here's an example of me copying over a file called `foo.sh` to the remote host:

```
scp -i mykey.pem foo.sh "ec2-user@ec2-123-123-123-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/usr/tmp/foo.sh"
```

in the example:

- `mykey.pem` is my .pem file
- `foo.sh` is the file I want to copy across
- `ec2-user` the user on the host
- `123-123-123-123` the (fake) public ip address of the host
- `/usr/tmp/foo.sh` the location where I want the file to be

Comment: In my case, the ec2 instance is not fixed one , these are spot agents whose ip will keep on changing on new launch. The command that  you have mentioned will work when the user will ssh into the linux machine. Is there any possibility to run this command directly from the receiver(AWS EC2). I have given a try to sshpass utility to achieve it, though i am getting permission error.